# Print objects from a text file to a list within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python script to read a text file with one line strings and just output it into the console to copy and paste

```
List.txt =
Mud
Water
Leaves
```

.

```
f = open('list.txt')
file_contents = f.read()
print("(The Dog Plays in the " + (file_contents) + ")" + " or ")
f.close()
```

.

Current Output:

```
python.exe C:/PycharmProjects/autofilter/test.py
(The Dog Plays in the Mud
Water
Leaves)
```

What I would like:

```
(The Dog Plays in the Mud) or (The Dog Plays in the Water) or (The Dog Plays in the Leaves)
```

With the parenthesis and "or's" And so on... Not sure how I can terminate the for loop so it doesnt append an "or" to the last string in the output.

Comment: Use `" or ".join()`

Comment: @MattDMo: You're forgetting the newlines at the end of each item (as well as the parentheses).

Comment: @martineau yes, I didn't include other steps like `.strip()` and balancing parens. I was leaving that as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: @MattDMo: My comment was mainly for the benefit of many of those readers — I intentionally didn't mention *everything* you left out.

Comment: @martineau as I recall, as soon as I posted that comment, Will da Silva posted their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978015/1426065) below with all the relevant info, so I just left it at that.

Comment: @MattDMo: Will pay more attention to timestamps in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This simple one-liner will do the trick for you:

```
' or '.join(f'(The Dog Plays in the {x})' for x in file_contents.splitlines())
```

I'd also recommend using a `with` block for your file handling:

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    print(' or '.join(f'(The Dog Plays in the {x})' for x in f.read().splitlines()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('list.txt')
file_contents = f.read()
file_contents=file_contents.splitlines()
for count,item in enumerate(file_contents):
    print("(The Dog Plays in the " + (item) + ")", end =" ")
    if len(file_contents)-1!=count:
        print ("or" , end =" ")
f.close()
```